# @available with pre-available iOS versions - missing properties

Tags: ios, swift, ios9

I've implemented such class:

```
class MapLayoutGuide: NSObject, UILayoutSupport {
    var insetLength: CGFloat = 0
    init(insetLength: CGFloat) {
        self.insetLength = insetLength
    }
    var length: CGFloat {
        return insetLength
    }
}
```

Everything was working fine, however there were new changes introduced with new iOS version: [Apple changelog](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/Miscellaneous/iOS90SeedAPIDiffs/modules/UIKit.html).

So now I'm receiving 3 errors:

- `Protocol requires property 'topAnchor' with type 'NSLayoutYAxisAnchor'`,
- `Protocol requires property 'bottomAnchor' with type 'NSLayoutYAxisAnchor'`,
- `Protocol requires property 'heightAnchor' with type 'NSLayoutDimension'`.

Looking into `UILayoutSupport` implementation I can see new variables:

```
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
var topAnchor: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor { get }
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
var bottomAnchor: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor { get }
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
var heightAnchor: NSLayoutDimension { get }
```

My app is `iOS 8.0+`. So the question is what should I do with these values..? I can't set `@available` flag and I want the code to work both with `iOS 8` and `9`, but I have to override it. No conception what to do with it.

The code used to work yesterday on `Xcode Beta 1`, what ofc doesn't matter atm as I want it to work on current API not previous.

Comment: The `@available` will tel you from which iOS version the method/property/class is available, this `@available(iOS 9.0, *)` mean available only on iOS 9 or higher. So you can not call these methods in iOS 8.

Comment: @rckoenes This I know, but I also have to override it (read errors). Now the question is how to implement it so it works both on iOS 9 and iOS 8. Please reread the question, especially the one before last paragraph (or if my question wasn't clear I hope now it is).

Comment: Sorry, yes now I get it. in iOS 9 those getter are required and need to be implemented. If you implement them they should work in iOS 8 since it doesn't call them.

Comment: @rckoenes Compiler claims I should add `@available(iOS 9.0, *)` statement, but it's for whole class, while I want the class to be available in `iOS 8` too.

Comment: Yes swift is strict in this way, but you I should work without the `@available`

Comment: @rckoenes I can't. Getting error: `'NSLayoutYAxisAnchor' is only available on iOS 9.0 or newer`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It worked after cleaning the project.

```
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
var topAnchor: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor {
    return NSLayoutYAxisAnchor()
}


@available(iOS 9.0, *)
var bottomAnchor: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor {
    return NSLayoutYAxisAnchor()
}


@available(iOS 9.0, *)
var heightAnchor: NSLayoutDimension {
    return NSLayoutDimension()
}
```